# How do you create an x-axis label with 2 label names or create 2 axis labels and specify their position?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06TG1.png)I am trying to define the position for a 2 name x-axis label. I have created the graph and would like an x-axis label that says N=5 under the first five bars and 'S' under the 6th bar. Is there a way to do this in python's matplotlib?

My bar plot contains 6 bars with varying eights depending on the feature I am plotting. I have a vertical line separating the last bar as this sample is unique. I am trying to label that last bar with a different x-axis label than the other 5 bars (which should have their own).

The link has my expected outcome. I have two boxes at the bottom for where I would like the x-axis labels demonstrating that the first five samples correspond to one group while the last sample is unique.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This isn't a problem with the code itself. I don't have any code that can do it is the problem, as I cannot find any instructions for how to create and orient multiple axis labels in matplotlib or how to split a single axis label and orient the parts under specific bars in a graph. In addition, I cannot share the code if I wanted to as HIPAA policy dictates the data I am working with cannot be displayed.

Comment: Then maybe a picture of your expected output?

Comment: The [mcve] is supposed to show what you have tried that doesn't work. It should not contain any confidential data, just some numbers you made up for the sake of an example. The reason you were asked for such example is two-fold: (1) People want to make sure you actually have tried something and they are not being misused as code-writing service, (2) People's time is limited, suppose they know a way to solve your problem, they might still decide not to answer here because it takes a significant amount of time to write the parts of the code that do not constitute the answer.

Comment: That being said, I don't think you're the first one with such a task, so there should be a bunch of (at least similar) questions around that would get you started. Knowing in how far they would not help would also allow readers to understand the problem better.